# what happens to view when published

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dll, compilation, hosting, recompile

When a site is published controllers are converted to dll, but what happen to views, for eg if new views are replaced by old, the site is not reset. Are the views compiled every time, someone calls it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first time a view is used, that view is compiled. The compiled version is cached in a temp folder. Subsequent calls check to see if the view source file has changed since it was compiled. If so, it recompiles and caches the new version. If it hasn't changed, the original cached version is used.

Comment: Side note: You can precompile views during the build process to save that first load hit. Though it has a few quirks, depends on which build system you use, and doesn't have a good UI to enable it.